# What's the meaning of __proto__ in the DevTools heap snapshot?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, v8

I've created an `A` object using the following code:

```
function A(){
    this.one = "one"
    this.two = "two"
    this[0] = "numeric index"
}
var objs = [];
for (var i=0; i<10;i++){
    // create 10 objects to get object size without slack/space for additional properties
    objs.push(new A())
}
objs.forEach(function(obj){
    obj.extraProperty = "extra"
})
```

As expected, the DevTools heap snapshot shows the size as 40 bytes:

- 2*8 bytes for the two properties `one` and `two`
- 8 bytes for `extra properties`
- 8 bytes for `elements` (numbered properties)
- 8 bytes for the hidden class

Based on this [explanation of V8 object representation](http://jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8-object-representation).

[image]

However, the heap snapshot also lists `__proto__` as a property, but I assume it doesn't add anything to the size of the object.

It is also already accessible as part of the hidden class/Map, so storing an additional reference to it isn't necessary.

[image]

Is the `__proto__` property just shown for convenience? How is it intended to be used?

Answer (score 2):

It has the same meaning as it already stands for. Instances have `__proto__`, classes have `prototype`.

```
function User(name){
    this.name = name
 }; 

var vinoth = new User("v");

vinoth.__proto__ == User.prototype //true
```

We have `new User()`, then `vinoth instanceof User is true`. `__proto__` look up helps up in looking up the Prototype Hierarchy which would point to `User.prototype` which would further point to `Object`, because **everything is an Object instance**. Further Heirarchy lead ends up to null.

`__proto__` is just a reference which chrome dev tool provides.

Comment: Yes, but why does it show up in the heap snapshot? It's not stored directly  on the object, but on `Object.prototype`.

Comment: Look at my updated answer.... basically its just a reference which chrome dev tool provides... ultimately everything is an Object instance... so you have properties which can be directly accessed in javascript...

Comment: Yes, but why does it show up in the heap snapshot if it's not an own property of the object, unlike the other properties?

Comment: @MattZeunert `system / *` stuff is only visible if you explicitly enable it - `__proto__` is there to make this connection between object and its prototype visible even if system properties themselves are hidden. Otherwise people would be extremely confused why object retains its prototype.

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov Ah, that makes sense. So there's a setting I've enabled to show the `system / *` stuff? (Just tried in a new profile and the hidden class shows up too.)

Comment: @MattZeunert there used to be, now that I look at Settings page, I don't see it anymore. It was called "Show advanced heap snapshot properties". Maybe it got defaulted to `true` at some point because everybody was enabling it anyway... Which makes showing `__proto__` obsolete

Comment: @MattZeunert here is the CL that removed the setting https://codereview.chromium.org/2188413004

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov Thanks so much for checking! Do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov And if you don't remove it, could you at least rename it to `[[prototype]]` please? To further deprecate `__proto__` as much as possible.